# How to drill into wood glue

Tags: wood, woodworking, drill, adhesive, epoxy

I tried drilling wood glue because I want to fix the screw there but I couldn't do it. The drill was not drilling a hole in glue and the screw did not fix there. I just want to make a proper hole in glue?

Are there issues with my tools or technique?

Can somebody properly guide me to make a hole in wood glue?

Comment: Suggestion: remove the glue completely, then glue in a wooden dowel that fills the cavity. When the glue dries, drill a pilot hole in the dowel and fix your screw into it.

Comment: At high speed, the glue might melt, reducing friction. Use a *sharp* drill bit at *lower* speed.

Comment: "The drill was not drilling a hole in glue" - elaborate please.

Comment: What exactly are your tools and technique?